# Lex: rule cannot be matched

Tags: parsing, lex

I get a warning for "[" and "]", but I don't know what the problem is.

lex.l:27: warning, rule cannot be matched

lex.l:28: warning, rule cannot be matched

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

delim [ \t\n]
ws {delim}+
digit [0-9]
number {digit}+
real_number [0-9]+\.[0-9]+([eE][0-9]+)?
sym [a-zA-z]
word {sym}+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
instruction [0-9xX]+

%%
{delim} {}
{instruction} { yylval.cval = yytext; return INSTRUCTION; }
{real_number} { yylval.dval = atof(yytext); return REAL_NUMBER; }
{word} { yylval.cval = strdup(yytext); return WORD; }

"--".* { /* empty */ }
":=" { return EQUATE; }
"[" |
"]" |
"(" |
")" |
";" |
":" |
"," |
"." |
"*" |
"\"" { return yytext[0]; }
%%

int yywrap (void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sym [a-zA-z]
```

is wrong, that should be:

```
sym [a-zA-Z]
```

Looks like `A-z` matches any character from `A` to `z` but between `Z` and `a` are included `[` and `]`.

Comment: "Looks like A-z matches any character from A to the end of the set of all characters" It matches everything between `A` and `z` in ASCII. That includes all upper case ASCII letters, all lower case ASCII letters, the characters `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` and the backtick character. It does not include ASCII characters that come after `z` (such as `{`), nor non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @sepp2k right! I was interpreting it as a-Z... stupid I am.